# Does “should” mean all 6 are required in “A maximum of 6...should be solved”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Can someone please explain this sentence to me?

> A maximum of 6 problems should be solved in a solution paper.

I am confused. Does this mean it is required to answer 6 problems in a paper? Or can I  write less than 6 in one paper?

I get that the maximum is the highest number possible. However, I'm confused about the "should." Does that mean it must be 6 in one paper?

Comment: Can you give us the link/source from where you got this sentence. It sounds weird.

Answer (score 1):

> A maximum of 6 problems should be solved in a solution paper.

[Maximum](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/maximum) denotes the highest limit or largest amount possible or allowed. That being said, you are expected to solve at the most 6 problems. That includes 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. Any number from 0 to 6 including both are allowed.

For your information, **at the most** means that specified number or lower/lesser. For e.g.

> I am considering of taking at the most 3 members in my group.

This would mean I can select 0, 1, 2, or 3 people, but no more for making my group.

'Maximum' and  'at the most' are synonymous.

---

**Minimum** and **at least**/**at the least** work just the opposite way around as compared to the above terms.

Answer (score 0):

You may attempt 5 or fewer. This might be to your advantage. You individually might get more marks for five complete questions instead of six partial questions. Or you may get more marks if you attempt the maximum six.

You should discuss with your teacher what the best advice is for you personally.

You should not attempt 7 or more.

It probably means that only the first six will be marked, or in some other way you would be at a disadvantage.

But while you could not benefit, it is not against the rules to answer 7 or more questions.  So this is strong advice, not a rule.